# Compute the unit vector for each row of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, linear-algebra

I have a large (n x dim) array, each row is a vector in a space (whatever the dimension but let's do it in 2D):

```python
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[50,14],[26,11],[81,9],[-11,-19]])

A.shape
 (4,2)
```

I want to quickly compute the unit vector for each of those rows.

```python
N = np.linalg.norm(A, axis=1)

# something like this, but for each row:
A /= N # not working: 
       # ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together
       # with shapes (4,2) (4,) (4,2)

# or in a pandas-like manner:
np.divide(A, N, axis=1, inplace=True) # not working either
```

How could you do that properly?

Comment: What is "not working"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) operation such as:

```python
A /= np.linalg.norm(A, axis=1)[:,None]
# or
A /= np.linalg.norm(A, axis=1).reshape(4,1)
```

which both will give the array a shape of `(4,1)` instead of `(4,)`

But beware, `A.dtype` should be `float64`* otherwise you will encounter this error when using [`ufunc`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html)

```python
A /= np.linalg.norm(A, axis=1)[:,None]

TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' output (typecode 'd') could not be coerced to     
           provided output parameter (typecode 'l') according to the casting     
           rule ''same_kind''
```

But doing it as follows will work, no matter the value of `A.dtype`:

```python
A = A/np.linalg.norm(A, axis=1)[:,None]
```

*
To initialize the array with `float64` you can simply add a comma to one of the numbers:

```python
A = np.array([[50.,14],[26,11],[81,9],[-11,-19]])
```

You can also use the [`normalize`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html) feature of [scikit learn](https://scikit-learn.org/)'s preprocessing toolbox:

```python
import sklearn
sklearn.__version__ # 0.24.2
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

normalize(A, norm="l2", axis=1)

array([[ 0.962964 ,  0.2696299],
       [ 0.9209673,  0.38964  ],
       [ 0.9938837,  0.1104315],
       [-0.5010363, -0.8654263]])

# as per the doc, you can set the copy flag to False to perform inplace row
# normalization and avoid a copy (if the input is already a numpy array or a
# scipy.sparse CSR matrix and if axis is 1):

normalize(A, norm="l2", axis=1, copy=False)

array([[ 0.962964 ,  0.2696299],
       [ 0.9209673,  0.38964  ],
       [ 0.9938837,  0.1104315],
       [-0.5010363, -0.8654263]])
```

Comment: It's much much more readable and simple to just use `keepdims=True`